# Flask Login with SQLite3

Tags: authentication, flask

I have written this code for my login, but I am unable to get it to work. Even when I enter a correct set of credentials stored in the database, the message: 'Invalid Credentials Please Try Again' is returned.

Could anyone provide some indication as to why this isn't working or provide a solution which would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
    def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.database)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        validate_user = validate(username, password)
        if validate_user == False:
            error = 'Invalid Credentials Please Try Again'
            return render_template('index.html', error=error)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('loggedin'))
    return render_template('index.html', error=error)

def validate(username, password):
    g.db = connect_db()
    Validation = False
    with g.db:
        cursor = g.db.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            database_user = row[1]
            database_password = row[2]
            if database_user == username:
                Validation = check_password(database_password, password)
    return Validation

def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
    return hashed_password == hashlib.md5(user_password.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your Users table has columns 'username' and 'password'

```
import sqlite3
from flask import g

DATABASE = '/path/to/database.db'

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        validate_user = validate(username, password)
        if validate_user == False:
            error = 'Invalid Credentials Please Try Again'
            return render_template('index.html', error=error)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('loggedin'))
    return render_template('index.html', error=error)

def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv

def validate(username, password):
    g.db = connect_db()
    user = query_db('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ?',
                    [username], one=True)

    return False if user is None else check_password(user['password'], password)

def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
    return hashed_password == hashlib.md5(user_password.encode()).hexdigest()
```